# changing the mount point of software raid enabled disk

Tags: raid, opensuse, partition

Basically what I want to achieve is the following.
I have two disks and have enabled software raid on these. The df shows the following:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc2             457G  205G  230G  71% /
devtmpfs              5.9G  300K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              230G   21G  198G  10% /vcs
```

As you see there are 198GB of space on /vcs, but what I want is to mount /dev/md0 to /data instead. The data currently stored under /vcs will be moved to /data/vcs/

Should I repartition the disk with fdisk and copy back the data on /vcs once finished or is it sufficient to change the fstab to mount to /data? I will still need the data on /vcs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps.
First create a directory `/vcs/vcs` and copy everything from `/vcs` into it.

```
cd /vcs
mkdir vcs
mv * vcs
```

Secondly, remount /vcs as /data.

```
mkdir /data
umount /vcs
mount /dev/md0 /data
```

Third (optional) step. Symlink /data/vcs to /vcs to keep the path if needed.

```
ln -s /data/vcs /vcs
```

Make sure you update your `/etc/fstab` to reflect the mountpoint change.
Before moving the data and unmounting the filesystem, make sure no applications are running or using the files to avoid data corruption or locked files.